# How to get the details of Instance using particular Elastic IP (EIP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, ethernet

How to get the details of Instance using particular Elastic IP (EIP). For example , I have an EIP with me and I don't know where its located?

Comment: You have both `aws-cli` and `aws-console` tagged. Which method do you wish to use?

Answer (score 1):

if you know the region you can use `describe-addresses` in aws cli:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --public-ips xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

{
"Addresses": [
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "PublicIp": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "AllocationId": "eipalloc-xxxxx",
        "AssociationId": "eipassoc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Domain": "vpc",
        "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxxxxx",
        "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "PublicIpv4Pool": "amazon"
    }
]
}
```

if you dont have the region you can use the [region table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) to find it.